# solr PatternTokenizerFactory not splitting

Tags: solr

I have the following tokenizer:

```
<analyzer type="index">
   <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
   <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="-|\\s+"/>
   <!-- more -->
```

When I go to the analysis page on my solr server, I can see that there is a PatternTokenizer, and that the PatternTokenizer is using the specified pattern.  Unfortunately, if I analyze something simple like:

```
1/2 test
```

The PatternTokenizer does not split the string at all, instead leaving it as one string.  **How do I make a regular expression that will split on whitespace or a "-"?**

The solr documentation (https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/pattern/PatternTokenizerFactory.html) implies that I should be able to give the PatternTokenizerFactory a regular expression and it will split the documents using that regular expression.  I checked the regular expression in a regular Java program:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class RegexTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String test = "a     b c-d/e";
        String[] rs = test.split("-|\\s+");
        System.err.println(Arrays.toString(rs));
    }
}
```

and got the following output, which suggests to me that there is nothing wrong with the regular expression.

```
[a, b, c, d/e]
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
<tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[-\s]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you can use whitespace filter factory and word delimiter filter factory.

I think that should solve your problem.

In the word delimiter filter factory , you need set the attribute generate word part as 1. Then it would generate tokens... Like for example...

Input is like Wi-Fi...it will generate tokens like wi, fi.

Here you can also preserve the original word by setting another attribute which preserve original.

If you have only - (hyphen) to be removed or replaced then you can think of the above.

If you a requirement of removing or replacing many other characters then can think of using patterns.